# Maria DB (Windows) backup

Tags: mariadb

We have just started a project with Maria DB (Windows) as backend. I have been asked to automate Maria DB backup process. What should be the best approach to automate Maria DB? Backup will be taken weekly. For now it is a small DB but will be growing in future.

Please help.

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-backup-overview/

Answer (score 0):

One way to automate the backup process would be to create a scheduled task on your database server that runs once every week (or how often the backups should be created).

The scheduled task can then trigger the [MariaDB Backup](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-backup-overview/) program or possibly [mysqldump](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqldump/), if you prefer that.

What you definitely should **not** do is just to copy the MariaDB data directory, because that can be problematic with InnoDB tables. It is not guaranteed to have the same format in different MariaDB versions, and the database could just change while the copy is created. So do not do that.

Comment: we have a small database now, which will grow gradually. What is the best option out of these. As I read MariaDB BAckup is to be installed whereas mysqldump can be used as a utility.Please suggest.

Comment: @Payal, both mariabackup, and mysqldump are installed by default, but you can opt out mariabackup (and you cannot mysqldump :)) if you want. mysqldump provides a better portability between versions, since its output is text, mariabackup gives you  faster speed.